# How x-permitted-cross-domain-policies is different from CORS(cross origin resource sharing)?

Tags: web-application, appsec, cors

OWASP is recommending x-permitted-cross-domain header. I gone through many websites and blogs and didn't get to know the difference between x-permitted-cross-domain and CORS. Since I have implemented CORS, is it required to have x-permitted-cross-domain header?

Kindly help.

Comment: See also [Does the X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies header have any benefit for my website if I'm not using Adobe products?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/166024/does-the-x-permitted-cross-domain-policies-header-have-any-benefit-for-my-websit)

Comment: Hi @Sjoerd, your mentioned ticket does not have the answer, I am looking for. Kindly provide some solid reference. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @PawanDwivedee: The  answer to the mentioned question is pretty clear when you need this header *"If your project is not using Flash and pdf, there is no need for that header."*. If this does not fit your question of *"Since I have implemented CORS, is it required to have x-permitted-cross-domain header?"* then it is unclear for me what you are actually asking.

Comment: Thanks @Steffen, Now it is clear by mentioning that it is for Flash and PDF only.